# Google Maps / Validation Error for specific address

Tags: google-address-validation-api

This is not a technical question.
How do I go about getting Google to correct a validation error?
This isn't a feature request and their bug reporting didn't read like that was the correct place either.  If this isn't the correct forum, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Anyway, here is the problem.

Correct address:
600 New Hampshire Ave NW, Washington, DC  20037

Google validates to:
2700 F St NW, Washington, DC  20566

All other services I've tried validate this address correctly.  2700 F St NW is the Kennedy Center.  600 New Hampshire Ave NW is the Watergate building, which is totally incorrect.

Maybe this has to do with the 600 block of New Hampshire Ave being renamed to Jamal Khashoggi Way, but, as I stated, all other services I've tried, including USPS validate this address as 600 New Hampshire Ave NW.

We are a delivery company using Google's API and this creates a real problem for our driver.

Thanks.

Comment: `This is not a technical question` Then it's off-topic. To request Google to correct their databases you have no choise but to contact Google. Stack Overflow can't do anything about that, nor any other forum.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [Report data or content errors on Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?hl=en).